# RestClient is returning StatusCode OK but the length is -1

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

Here's my code below:

```
var client = new RestClient(allEmployeeCallLink);
string _path = @"pathToTheCert";
var certFile = Path.Combine(_path, "ACTUALCERT.pfx");
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFile);
client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection() { certificate };
client.Proxy = new WebProxy();
//client.Timeout = -1;
var restrequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
restrequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
//restrequest.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteGetAsync(restrequest);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

My issue is that the response is returning something that basically says "I am starting the call now".  I made the same call in Postman and was able to return the correct items which is a large list of employees.  What I'm getting back when making the call in C# is:

```
{
   "confirmMessageID": {
     "idValue":"ID",
     "schemeName":"confirmMessageID",
     "schemeAgencyName":"WFN"
   },
   "processingStatusCode":{
         "codeValue":"started"
   }
}
```

I guess I'm not sure how to make the response make a call with executeAsync and have it wait to return any results until the content length is not equal to -1.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Download, install and run Fiddler. Execute both requests. Compare them in Fiddler. You will have your answer.